# Sharepoint 2013 Workflows with Survey | Design Question

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, survey

My goal is to create a feedback process entirely in SharePoint 2013. The Owner can start a workflow which creates a Survey from a template. The users then fill out the survey and once its done, the data gets processed in SharePoint (not via Excel, because this would include manual effort). Another Workflow gets the results from the survey and stores them in a folder in a list, because the same survey are taken each year and the data has to be stored for several years. With the data in the list, we than can make some graphs and statistics and display them on the homepage of the SharePoint site. There should also be workflows to remind user to fill out the survey, and to help the owner keep track on which survey is open.

**Each year there are about 50 surveys taken place**

Do you think SharePoint is designed to handle this, or do you have any other recommendation how I could solve the problem?

I do have access to SharePoint Designer 2013 and have some basic HTML / CSS / JS skills, but never worked with Workflows before.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.

1. Easy way - use **Microsoft Forms** + **MS Flow** (to send reminder notifications)
   MS Forms are super easy to build and creates nice graphs by themselves[image]
   I'm adding the link to how reminder notifications can be setup for MS flow when using MS forms - solution by v-xida-msft

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Reminder-mail-to-microsoft-forms-survey/td-p/81668

All the data submitted in the form can be exported to excel. Or you can Create a MS flow to store the form data to a SharePoint list

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-forms/ms-forms-data-stored-in-sharepoint-list/m-p/279290

2. Slightly more difficult way - Use **MS Powerapps** (to build the form) and **MS flow** to send reminder notifications

I do not recommend using SharePoint designer since it has now been replaced by MS flow and it will soon be reaching its end of lifecycle on 2026

Hopefully this is Useful !

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. As I stated in the Title I'm working with Sharepoint 2013 on premise and therefore cannot use Microsoft Forms, MS Powerapps or MS Flow...